# Android studio uploading old apk when changing project.archivesBaseName

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I have configured build.gradle so it increases version code in version.properties each time I create a release build. I also use version code for the apk filename. However Android studio seems to ignore the version changes so when I run debug build from the ide then assemble Release build using console (which increases the version number) and then run debug from IDE again, it correctly builds an apk with the increased version in the filename BUT uploads the old  apk to the device.

So for examle lets have a version code=377.

1. Run debug build from IDE-> builds and uploads
   GradleTestApp-v1.5(**377**)-debug-unaligned.apk
2. do gradle assambleRelease -> builds 
   GradleTestApp-v1.5(**377**)-release-unsigned.apk and then increases
   versionCode to 378
3. Run debug build from IDE again -> builds
   GradleTestApp-v1.5(**378**)-debug-unaligned.apk (correct behavior)
   however uploads the old GradleTestApp-v1.5(**377**)-debug-unaligned.apk to the
   device

What am I missing?

Here is my gradle script:

```
ext{
    versionPropFile = 'version.properties'
    Properties versionProps =  getVersionProps()
}
project.archivesBaseName=project.archivesBaseName+"-v"+versionProps['name'] + "(" + versionProps['code']+")"


def Properties getVersionProps(){
    def Properties versionProps = new Properties()
    versionProps.load(new FileInputStream(file(versionPropFile)))
    return versionProps
}

task('increaseVersionCode') << {
    def Properties versionProps = new Properties()
    versionProps.load(new FileInputStream(file(versionPropFile)))
    int versionCode = versionProps['code'].toInteger()
    versionProps['code'] = (versionCode+1)+""
    versionProps.store(new FileOutputStream(file(versionPropFile)), "App version properties")
    println 'increasing version code to ' + versionProps['code']
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "18.0.1"
        ...
}

assembleRelease.dependsOn('increaseVersionCode')
```

Comment: Hi. Have you solved this ?

Comment: I am having this exact issue did you figure it out?

Comment: You likely need to somehow trigger a gradle sync